# Заголовок-ссылка

Tags: html

Если мне нужно сделать заголовок-ссылку, то как будет правильнее - положить ссылку в тег заголовка

```
<h3><a href="/news/news_4.html">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></h3>
```

или наоборот?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно будет сделать так как у Вас. То есть вложить ссылку внутрь заголовка.

Строчный элемент не может содержать в себе блочный. Почитайте спецификацию.

Удачи.

Comment: да, действительно. спасибо)

Comment: Сейчас проверил... Если вы пишите на HTML5, то в данной спецификации, обратная структура:

    <a href="#"><h1>Heidel</h1></a>

так же возможна. То есть документ проходит проверку на валидность.

Comment: нет, верстка не на html5, но спасибо, очень интересно.